Paper Discussion - Hamiltonian Neural Networks
Im writing a paper on the discoveries made by Sam Greydanus et al.: https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.01563v1
I was wondering if anyone could help me provide some insights on this:
They are highlighting how making the model predict the Hamiltonian directly, and deriving the gradients dp/dt and dq/dt from the Frameworks axioms gives better results:
[![Hamiltonian Dynamics relationship momentum and position][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Im4x43Wk.png
And they do get great results, even better than a traditional neural network that directly predicts the gradients. The HNN creates a mapping that correctly conserves the energy of ideal pendulums etc.
My question is: Why is this important? Aren´t we just enforcing bias. And if our goal with using neural networks is to model complex systems why enforce an existing framework?
The model will only be as accurate as the framework, and wouldnt it be more interesting to make neural networks discover these frameworks and mappings themself. Since the real world is to some degree predictable there should be an underlying framework that comes with mappings more accurate than a manmade framework. We have millions of parameters in a neural network compared to a few in an Analytical/Numerical solution?
I may be completely off here (im just an engineering student), but i think discussing this in my paper as well as actually discussing the results may be a cool angle.

The dominant issue in learning differential equation from data with neural networks is that differential equations learned or solved by neural networks typically do not obey the same conservation laws, stability properties, etc. as the systems from which the data is gathered. Enforcing this "bias" as you say, is a way of ensuring that the cheaper model you are calibrating remains stable in some sense for out-of-sample predictions. These models with imposed structure are typically only used when the existence of that structure is justified or is prefered for numerical reasons.
Edit: After thinking about this a bit more and seeing it get migrated to CrossValidated from MSE, I thought I would add add and clarify a few points. For the purpose of the below discussion, consider the model problem
$$
\min_\theta~\sum_{i=1}^M(y_i - y(t_i;\theta))^2 \\ \mathrm{s.t.}~\frac{dy}{dt}=NN(t,y;\theta), \ y(0)=y_0
$$

Modeling considerations

You are absolutely correct that imposing Hamiltonian, Newtonian, entropy-increasing, etc. conditions on the structure of the neural network dramatically impact the resulting dynamics and the fidelity of the resulting model fit. For example, imposing energy conservation can render the neural network completely unable to fit data from some sort of forced or driven process. From the perspective of removing bias, it many sound more reasonable to just impose that $NN(\cdot)$ be a fully connected network, appeal to the universal approximation theorem, and be done with it. However, from traditional machines learning, we know that adding these structural constraints can massively improve the fidelity and efficiency of learned models.
For example, convolutional neural networks are generally far superior at image learning tasks than fully connected networks precisely because of the structural bias they impart on the learned models. Convolutional kernels induce a banded sparsity pattern on the network, which theoretically leaves out a lot of potential pixel-pixel interactions, but we know that much of the building blocks of image learning come from small local structures that can be picked up by these convolutional layers. Here we are leveraging problem information to impose structural constraints to more efficiently solve the problem.

Numerical considerations

There are many reasons for the recent increase in research in the intersection of differential equations and machine learning, but one of the primary ones is the relative lack of numerical tools and expertise to properly train them. The primary issue is that in both evaluating the model and computing its gradient, you need to solve a differential equation. Generally speaking, machine learning researchers are not good at this. Any bottleneck at this step will massively hamper training and prediction efficiency. This ignores the fact that computing the gradient of the map $\theta\mapsto y(t_i;\theta)$ is already quite involved and tends to require your entire numerical ODE solver to be rewritten for use with automatic differentiation tools, or you have to resort to adjoints which are quite difficult to implement in a stable and memory-efficient manner. Returning to the issue of efficiency of numerical ODE solvers, there is more than a century's worth of research on the topic that basically amounts to the following: There are no one-size-fits-all numerical ODE solvers.
This immediately leads us to issues if we wish to use a fully-connected neural network as a one-size-fits-all surrogate model for our learned ODE. If the numerical ODE algorithm is chosen incorrectly, it can lead to inaccurate solutions, training that crashes randomly, or slowdowns by orders of magnitude. Furthermore, we can select an ODE solver that works well initially, but it can become ill-suited as $\theta$ is subsequently updated. There are some sophisticated methods that can be used to alleviate some of this, such as adaptive timesteps, adaptive order, and stiffness detection and switching, but such methods are often only found in purpose-built ODE libraries that are ill-suited to AD or are unfamiliar to many ML practitioners. Indeed, selecting a proper numerical ODE solver or even knowing about available methods for a given problem class is something that eludes many mathematicians.
However, if we impose additional structure on our neural network, we can appeal to the wealth of research in numerical integration to choose an integration scheme that is stable and optimized for our problem class. For example, there are integrators that are highly optimized for Hamiltonian systems and excel at energy conservation. Similarly there are purpose-built methods for dissipative systems, Newtonian systems, highly oscillatory systems, and more. If we are able to restrict our model class a priori, we are typically able to find a much more efficient integration method that will improve the efficiency and stability of training and prediction.

"For example. Convolutional kernels induce a banded sparsity pattern on the network, which theoretically leaves out a lot of potential pixel-pixel interactions, but we know that much of the building blocks of image learning come from small local structures that can be picked up by these convolutional layers. Here we are leveraging problem information to impose structural constraints to more efficiently solve the problem."
This did it for me, thank you
